# Why was Camus wrong that suicide is a really serious philosophical problem, let alone the fundamental question of philosophy?

Tags: camus

[r/AskPhilosophy](https://redd.it/1tjb67) construed the following quotation from [*Le Mythe de Sysyphe*: Chapitre 1](https://genius.com/Albert-camus-le-mythe-de-sysyphe-chapitre-1-annotated), which [Alan Watts joked](https://redd.it/v0y7z) about. Emboldenings are mine.

> **Il n'y a qu'un problème philosophique vraiment sérieux : c'est le suicide.** **Juger que la vie vaut ou ne vaut pas la peine d'être vécue, c'est répondre à la question fondamentale de la philosophie.** Le reste, si le monde a trois dimensions, si l'esprit a neuf ou douze catégories, vient ensuite. Ce sont des jeux ; il faut d'abord répondre. Et s'il est vrai, comme le veut Nietzsche, qu'un philosophe, pour être estimable, doive prêcher d'exemple, on saisit l'importance de cette réponse puisqu'elle va précéder le geste définitif. Ce sont là des évidences sensibles au cœur, mais qu'il faut approfondir pour les rendre claires à l'esprit.

[Translation by Hélène Brown:](https://philosophy.lander.edu/ethics/camus-brown.pdf)

> **There is only one truly serious philosophical problem: suicide. To
> judge whether life is or is not worth living amounts to answering the
> fundamental question of philosophy.** The rest—whether the world
> has three dimensions, whether the mind has nine or twelve cate-
> gories—comes afterwards. These are games; one must answer first.
> And, if it is true, as Nietzsche claims, that a philosopher should
> preach by example in order to command respect, one begins to un-
> derstand the importance of that reply, for it will precede the defini-
> tive act. These are truths the heart can feel, yet they must be exam-
> ined in depth to become clear to the mind.

#### Can someone elaborate  [Conifold's comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/76234/if-suicide-is-the-very-serious-philosophical-problem-why-doesnt-philosophy-of/76240#comment211123_76234)? Which philosophers disagree with this quotation above? Why isn't suicide a "*vraiment sérieux*" (really serious) "*problème philosophique*" (philosophical problem), let alone "*la question fondamentale de la philosophie*" (the fundamental problem of philosophy)? What did Camus muff?

> Because few philosophers share Camus' opinion. To them, suicide is serious as a social and psychological problem, but not as a philosophical one. People who commit suicide almost never do it for philosophical reasons, it is typically an emotional act, perhaps fueled by social circumstances, so its scientific study is more productive. Philosophically, it comes up mostly due to ethical aspects.

Comment: Ok, my French is only suitable for swearing, so I pushed the translate button and to me the primary sentence is: "*To judge that life is or is not worth living ...*" Back then they were grappling with a sense that life was meaningless. This is an emergency, so of course it eclipsed all other questions. One could choose not to have children, but not to not have been born, so the only way to change one's mind is the title action. It was not considered a 'problem' in itself, so reading it that way is getting it very wrong, a kind of use-mention error. Focus on the meaning aspect.

Comment: It's Google Translate

Comment: The translation is good.

Comment: Simple: because Camus' logic is flawed: of course, people dead by suicide can't make philosophy, but that doesn't imply that categories are secondary to suicide. To me, Camus' philosophy is shallow and just discoursive, imagine him, a coffee in Paris, surrounded by beautiful girls... wow! Suicide is very no no no!

Comment: Camus states that to him philosophy is about finding the meaning of life and as such, also suicide (because if life is meaningless why not end it now?). As such he is not wrong, as he can define his terms the way he sees fit, but others might have other definitions. There are philosophers who consider their practice to be about only the formalization, critique and organization of concepts, and see "the meaning of life" as one of those pesky questions that human reason can't dismiss but can't answer Kant was speaking about.

Comment: Hehe, my answer was deleted and cut, and published as a comment on my behalf. Okey i ll edit full version:
"Dear CriglCragl, It was Camus's inner monologue, don't take it personally and share with self. You can't drink "Cumus's" cap of coffee, you can only follow his preach, so, all you think about it definitely meaningless, but examined. Don't try to live Sisyphus's or Camus's life. "I do it by self" - that is Camus said. "Should I kill myself, or have a cup of coffee?" Both acts are equally meaningless. But to continue play someone needed a courage("heart, innermost feelings; temper").

Comment: But to be someone is not same to cosplay someone. So don't share Camus's thoughts, but make separate self inner monologue, and Camus inner monologue. Make them separate and break the Camus's monologue in self mind.

And answer the question. Camus can't be wrong, wrong way can be if it is sharing other's inner monologues with self one. Don't have to assign someone's monologue or share it. Don't have to. It is impossible to steal someone's inner monologue, as to drink someone's imagine cap of coffee.
If you create and idol, you ll blame the idol for your mistakes.

Comment: But it is not a mistake.

It is a principle.

Philosophers live in the version of the reality where no one is wrong. It is obliviously clear.

Why suicide is meaningless? Cuz you can to know how it be self dead. So the inner monologue about death nature is introduced from the life game, it can't be self thought."

that was my answer, thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm particularly intrigued by the juxataposition of Socrates with Camus:

*"The unexamined life is not worth living."*  ~ Socrates.

*"The examined life is not worth living."* ~ Camus (would've said)

Camus' *meaning of life* is what has been dubbed as *cosmic meaning*, a *higher purpose* as some like to call it, such as can only be *conferred upon* one by, *sensu amplissimo*, god(s). However grand such a meaning may be, it's to surrender one's *autonomy* and *self-determination*, the power to control one's own destiny. Thus, on this view, *meaningless* = *freedom*. It makes zero sense to suicide *because* one is *free* (one's life is "meaningless").

Comment: You imply that is a direct Camus quote. It's not. It's not what he said, or meant. Please amend your answer. You also seem not to have read Camus. He absolutely did not dismiss suicide, he saw it as something constantly to be grappled with. *"Should I kill myself, or have a cup of coffee? But in the end one needs more courage to live than to kill himself."*

Comment: @CriglCragl, please reread my post. Camus is of the view that *because* life is *meaningless* one is quite naturally driven to suicide. However *meaning* to Camus is some kinda *grand meaning* bestowed by god(s) [read *master(s), a *slave mentality*].

Comment: How is "We must imagine Sisyphus happy" a bestowing by gods? He says our labours are as fundamentally pointless, but we should choose that "The struggle itself towards the heights is enough to fill a man's heart" For Camus meaning is deeply, intrinsically, personal.

Comment: @CriglCragl, I edited my post. Danke for calling my attention to possible disinformation, even if unintended.

Comment: @CriglCragl, To *imagine Sisyphus happy* means that though Sisyphus has no reason to be happy, he should be happy. I'm saying that's not true. Sisyphus actually has a good reason to be happy.

Comment: That isn't Camus' point though. It is yours.

Comment: Isn't the *meaninglessness* of life a conclusion of the *examination* of *life* by Albert Camus? @CriglCragl

Comment: Yes, not "cosmic meaning, a higher purpose". His point was you can't *find* or *be given* meaning, you must choose or make meaning through engaging with the absurdity of our need for what is impossible. Comments are not for extended discussion. I think your answer is incorrect, & I have explained why.

Comment: @CriglCragl, then why isn't Sisyphus happy?

Comment: This is a very different reading of the Myth of Sisyphus than I remember.

Comment: i would say that should read the examined life appears not to be worth living (but is)

Comment: @not_me_either if one stops examining and gets on with living.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Camus was focusing on suicide, or commenting on the ethics of suicide at all as much as on the possible meaninglessness of existence. He was pointing out that existence may or may not be meaningless to oneself, and if it is meaningless, and you follow through, then exiting this meaningless situation is a possibility.

He clearly says as much: the fundamental question is for one to decide whether life has a meaning or not, and that's what he is interested in. Not really if one should commit suicide or not, if that's ethical or not, etc etc. Suicide comes as a consequence once you decide whether life has a meaning or not, and if you assume that absence of meaning necessarily leads to suicide (and as he says, if you believe like Nietzsche that a philosopher should lead by example).

I also think that Camus will eventually find an existentialist way to avoid the path of meaningless that would lead to suicide. Camus is not advocating that life is meaningless hence one should commit suicide.

Comment: Right, it is just a further development of the statement attributed to Socrates. Examination does not of itself make life meaningful, we have to go beyond that, regardless what is found. *Living* makes life meaningful.

Comment: @ScottRowe I think the context around Camus is pretty disconnected from Socrates. I don't think Camus is thinking about the examined life, as much as radical, existential meaninglessness, then acting to define one's life.

Comment: Fair enough. I would propose a kind of Pascal's Wager to say: you can't be sure life is 'meaningless', so don't take your own life, because the cost of being wrong is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

The experience of the absurd, from which we experience the futility of life (fully enough to make suicide a fundamental question, despite the evils of death), has an intellectual context of **seeking meaning when there is none**.

If we're unaware we seek meaning,  we do not realise it cannot be found, not enough for suicide due to the hopelessness of that to be a fundamental question. Why bother if we already agree life is meaningless?

> What is the Camusean alternative to suicide or hope? The answer is to
> live without escape...
> maintaining the [absurd] tension intrinsic to human life [of seeking meaning when there is none]... [a life] characterized
> by **lucidity** and by **acute consciousness of...
> mortality and... [life's] limits**.

Comment: you could draw a graph... want 'meaning' have 'meaningless' reject 'hope' which means 'futile' but shouldn't 'suicide' and should 'rebel' LOOP

Comment: I like your additional quote. People seem to get stuck and not follow the loop around enough times to see how to get free of it.

Answer (score 0):

Camus was not even wrong about what you are asking, because the focus of what he was saying was to get at the apparent *meaninglessness* of existence. You can find an answer from Milarepa about 800 years ago:

> All worldly pursuits have but one unavoidable and inevitable end, which is sorrow; acquisitions end in dispersion; buildings in destruction; meetings in separation; births in death. Knowing this, one should, from the very first, renounce acquisitions and storing-up, and building, and meeting; and, following the guidance of an eminent Guru, set about to know the real truths, which have no birth or death.

Many people have found this approach to address their concerns, although it takes some commitment. But, if you were wondering if existence is worthwhile, you have all the time in the world.

Comment: Excellent quote, all systems organize and disperse. But I don't see the relationship between this mechanism and suicide.

Comment: @RodolfoAP well, there is the word 'death' sitting there, but no: as I said, suicide is not relevant, meaninglessness is. Camus wrote a great clickbait statement, but we need to read past the headline for the full story.

Comment: So, this answer is: systems organize and disperse. Life is meaningless. If you want to know why suicide has a relation with that, you have to buy the full product (read past the headline, "You have all the time in the world"). That's not an answer at all. You can write an explicit argument. If done well, normally you need one sentence. Can you, please? Thanks.

Comment: @RodolfoAP You only get the benefit of living if you are around to cash in at the end, so stay, explore, enjoy. Put up with the inevitable problems and pain, and be a benefit to others, who are in many ways just like you. "*In Lak'ech*" (I am another yourself)

Comment: Nice self-motivating memes, but they have no relationship with suicide being the fundamental problem in philosophy, and with suicide being such thing because systems disperse. You see? One sentence is enough.

Comment: @RodolfoAP "*Life is not a rehearsal.*" The hearse will come soon enough. The fault is not in ourselves, but in what we choose to think.